# Using SQL "CAST" within LINQ

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, wcf

I'm trying to get XMl from my SQL database, using `CAST` withing the query.

This is how I tried to make it work:

```
string str = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT CAST(CAST(Content AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS DashboardXML FROM ReportServer$SRVSQL2012.dbo.Catalog WHERE Name = 'DannyTest.xml'").FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

But this doesn't really work as all `<` and `>` get's replaced by `&lt` and `&gt`.

How does one accomplish such task with pure LINQ? Can it even be done?

**EDIT**

I'm not even sure if this is a service problem or what it is that actually replaces the `<`and `>`?

**EXAMPLE OF OUTCOME**

```
&lt;Dashboard CurrencyCulture="da-DK"&gt
```

should be

```
<Dashboard CurrencyCulture="da-DK">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Instead of using the `XElement.load("whatever")` I used the `XElement.Parse("whatever")` since the output from the LINQ statement is a string.

Like so:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(
    db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
        "SELECT CAST(CAST(Content AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) 
        AS DashboardXML FROM ReportServer$SRVSQL2012.dbo.Catalog WHERE Name = 'DannyTest.xml'")
    .FirstOrDefault<string>());
```

This way, the string got converting correctly into a readable XML